# Compile all still not compiled templates with JS and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, compilation, handlebars.js, html-templates

So i'm having this HTML file with a bunch of  templates that I would want to compile at the start of loading the page. They can either be compiled all at once and then stored into an array(probably) or when you would go to a page of the SPA it would either compile and store the template of the page, or, if it was already compiled, just find and use the compiled page without the need to repeatedly compile the same page every time you visit it.
I'm using JS and Handlebars.js, could you please help me with some advice on how to achieve the goal? Currently there is a function that doesn't work that I need to modify and implement:

```
function compile_template(template) {
    var template_source;
    if (templates_compiled[template] === undefined)
        {
            template_source = $("#" + template).html();
            return Handlebars.compile(template_source);
        }
}
```

That is after used as follows:

```
template = "template_projects";
        templates_compiled[template] = compile_template(template);

        $("#div_page_data_container").html(templates_compiled[template](page_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what the root cause of your issue is. I suspect there are issues outside of the code provided that are having an effect.

However, I can make some recommendations that I believe will make your caching function easier to work with.

The first problem I see is that your `compile_template` function reads from the `templates_compiled` cache object but does not write to it. This means that the code that calls `compile_template` must "remember" to always add the result from the `compile_template` to `templates_compiled`.

Secondly, `compile_template` returns nothing (ie., `undefined`) when the `templates_compiled[template] === undefined` evaluates to `false`. This puts the responsibility on the calling code to check if `templates_compiled[template]` has a value *before* calling `compile_template`. The condition in `compile_template` "leaks" the abstraction of the cache lookup, forcing the calling code to "know" the internals of `compile_template`.

I would re-write the caching function so that it is the *only* part of code that needs to know about the cache. Here is an example:

```
const compiledTemplates = {};
function getCompiledTemplate(key) {
  if (compiledTemplates[key]) {
    return compiledTemplates[key];
  }
  
  const templateSource = $(`#${key}`).html();
  const compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
  
  compiledTemplates[key] = compiledTemplate;
  
  return compiledTemplate;
}

let template;
template = getCompiledTemplate('template_projects'); // template not found in cache, is freshly compiled by Handlebars
template = getCompiledTemplate('template_projects'); // compiled template is returned from `compiledTemplates` cache
```